# Restrict access to a Google Cloud bucket to a certain IP range

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I wanted to check if it's possible to restrict access to a Google Cloud bucket to a certain IP range and if yes how can we restrict the access.  We are exposing our cloud bucket to a vendor and we want to restrict the bucket access only  to the vendors IP range.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for this is [VPC Service Controls](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/overview). This allows you to define a [service perimeter](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/create-service-perimeters) that includes your project's GCS service and add an [access level](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/use-access-levels) to allow access from the IPs you want.

Comment: Hi... can we use Cloud Load Balancer to set static IP for our bucket. This link https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/ext-load-balancer-backend-buckets describes how to do it.  However in our case we are pushing a file into the  cloud bucket and not  fetching from the cloud bucket.